# pager not working with custom reports

Tags: paging

I have custom reporting which has few dropdowns.
A report is generated in the form of a table with selected dropdown values.

I have tried adding pager to the table.

When I click on next page, all the form values loose their form state and page is reloaded back and table gets disappeared.

Im using 'drupal_get_form' in pagecallback in the menu items list.

Here is the code to generate report.

```
/**
 * Method to implement menu for this page
 *
 * @return multitype:multitype:string multitype:string
 */

function dm_reports_menu() {
    return array (
            'dm_reports' => array (
                    'title' => 'Reports',
                    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
                    'page arguments' => array (
                            'dm_reports_form' 
                    ),
                    'access callback' => 'user_access',
                    'access arguments' => array (
                            'administer dm_reports' 
                    ) 
            ) 
    );
}


/**
 * Method to submit the form and generate report
 *
 * @param unknown $form         
 * @param unknown $form_state           
 */
function dm_reports_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $circle_name = $form_state ['values'] ['circle_name'];
    $report_type = $form_state ['values'] ['choose_report'];
    $system_type = $form_state ['values'] ['system_type'];
    $office_name = $form_state ['values'] ['office_name'];
    $migration_type = $form_state ['values'] ['migration_type'];
    $from_date = get_date_SQL ( $form_state ['input'] ['from_date'] );
    $to_date = get_date_SQL ( $form_state ['input'] ['to_date'] );
    $plan_type = $form_state ['values'] ['plan_type'];
    $phase_type = $form_state ['values'] ['phase'];
    $vendor_name=$form_state ['values'] ['vendor_name'];

    if ($form_state ['values'] ['op'] == 'Generate Report') {

        // Report header
        $header = get_header_data ( $report_type, $system_type );
        $rows = array ();
        // Get rows data
        try {

            $rows = get_row_data ( $report_type, $circle_name, $office_name, $system_type, $migration_type, $from_date, $to_date, $plan_type, $form_state,$phase_type,$vendor_name );
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            form_set_error ( '', t ( 'Error occurred. Please try again, or report a problem to administrator.'.$e ) );
            watchdog ( 'atm_status', $e->getMessage (), NULL, WATCHDOG_ERROR );
        }
        $report_name = '';
        if (sizeof ( $rows ) > 0) {
            $report_name = $report_type .'_' . date ( 'd_M_Y_H_i_s', time () ) . '.xls';
    //      generate_xls ( $header, $rows, $report_name);
        }
        $form_state ['report_name'] = $report_name;



        // build the results table
        $form_state['results_table'] = array (
                '#title' => $report_type,
                '#theme' => 'table',
                '#header' => $header,
                '#rows' => $rows,
                '#sticky' => TRUE,
                '#empty' => t ( 'NO DATA FOUND.' ) 
        // '#prefix' => '<hr><strong>' . $report_type . '</strong><div style="width: 720px; height: 300px; overflow: auto;">',
        // '#suffix' => '</div>'
        );


        $form_state ['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    }

}

function get_dm_issues_data($circle_name,$office_name)
{
$rows = array ();

    $query = db_select('dm_issues', 'di')
    ->extend('PagerDefault')
    ->limit(3)
    ->fields('di');

    $results = $query->execute();

    foreach ( $results as $node ) {
        $rows [] = array (

                $node->de_date,
                $node->po_name,
                //$node->weg_code,
                $node->kvp_duplicates,
                $node->nsc_duplicates,
                $node->duplicate_int_ent,
                $node->no_int,
                $node->nominee_grt_one,
                $node->account_his_na,
                $node->comments

        );
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

Any help would ne appreciated.

Comment: where is your "dm_reports_form" function ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function dm_reports_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $REPORT_TYPE = array (
            ATM_STATUS_SUMMARY_REPORT => ATM_STATUS_SUMMARY_REPORT,
            ATM_STATUS_DETAILED_REPORT => ATM_STATUS_DETAILED_REPORT,
            BRANCH_HARDWARE_SUMMARY_REPORT => BRANCH_HARDWARE_SUMMARY_REPORT,
            BRANCH_HARDWARE_DETAILED_REPORT => BRANCH_HARDWARE_DETAILED_REPORT,
            CPC_STATUS_REPORT => CPC_STATUS_REPORT,
            DATA_CLEANSING_SUMMARY_REPORT => DATA_CLEANSING_SUMMARY_REPORT,
            DATA_CLEANSING_DETAILED_REPORT => DATA_CLEANSING_DETAILED_REPORT,
            DAILY_STATUS_REPORT => DAILY_STATUS_REPORT,
            DATA_CAPTURE_STATUS_SUMMARY_REPORT => DATA_CAPTURE_STATUS_SUMMARY_REPORT,
            DATA_CAPTURE_STATUS_DETAILED_REPORT => DATA_CAPTURE_STATUS_DETAILED_REPORT,
            DATA_CAPTURE_DETAILED_SUMMARY_REPORT => DATA_CAPTURE_DETAILED_SUMMARY_REPORT,
            DATA_CAPTURE_STATUS_FOR_PAYMENT_REPORT => DATA_CAPTURE_STATUS_FOR_PAYMENT_REPORT,
            POVsVendor_STATUS_SUMMARY_REPORT=>POVsVendor_STATUS_SUMMARY_REPORT,
            PRODUCT_WISE_DATA_CAPTURE_DETAILED_REPORT => PRODUCT_WISE_DATA_CAPTURE_DETAILED_REPORT,
            DATA_MIGRATION_SUMMARY_REPORT => DATA_MIGRATION_SUMMARY_REPORT,
            DATA_MIGRATION_DETAILED_REPORT => DATA_MIGRATION_DETAILED_REPORT,
            PROBLEMS_REPORTED => PROBLEMS_REPORTED,
            ROLLOUT_DASHBOARD => ROLLOUT_DASHBOARD,
            ROLLOUT_PLANNING_REPORT => ROLLOUT_PLANNING_REPORT,
            TRAINING_STATUS_REPORT => TRAINING_STATUS_REPORT,
            DM_SUMMARY_REPORT => DM_SUMMARY_REPORT,
            DM_ISSUES_REPORT => DM_ISSUES_REPORT,
            DE_STATUS_DASHBOARD => DE_STATUS_DASHBOARD
              // GoLiveVsPO_NOT_STARTED => GoLiveVsPO_NOT_STARTED,
             // GoLiveVsPO_COMPLETED => GoLiveVsPO_COMPLETED 
    );

$system_types = array (
        CBS => CBS,
        PLI => PLI 
);

$migration_types = array (
        MOCK_MIGRATION => MOCK_MIGRATION,
        FINAL_MIGRATION => FINAL_MIGRATION 
);

$plan_types = array (
        END_USER_TRAINING_PLAN => END_USER_TRAINING_PLAN,
        USER_CHAMP_TRAINING_PLAN => USER_CHAMP_TRAINING_PLAN,
        DATA_CAPTURE_PLAN => DATA_CAPTURE_PLAN,
        MOCK_MIGRATION_PLAN => MOCK_MIGRATION_PLAN 
);

$phase = array (
        ALL=> ALL,
        PHASE_PILOT => PHASE_PILOT,
        "1000 PO" => "1000 PO",
        PHASE_1A => PHASE_1A,
        PHASE_1B => PHASE_1B,
        PHASE_2A => PHASE_2A,
        PHASE_2B => PHASE_2B 
);

$form = array ();
$form ['#attributes'] = array (
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data' 
);

$form ['choose_report'] = array (
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t ( 'Choose Report' ),
        '#options' => $REPORT_TYPE 
);



$form ['phase'] = array (
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t ( 'Phase' ),
        '#options' => $phase,
        '#states' => array (
                'invisible' => array ( // Making circle name list invisible if report selected is PROBLEMS_REPORTED
                        ':input[name=choose_report]' => array (
                                array (
                                        'value' => PROBLEMS_REPORTED 
                                ),
                                //array (
                                //      'value' => DM_SUMMARY_REPORT 
                                //),
                                //array (
                                //      'value' => DM_ISSUES_REPORT 
                                //),
                                array (
                                        'value' => DE_STATUS_DASHBOARD 
                                ),
                            )
                        )
                    )
);  


$circle_names [ALL] = ALL;
$circle_names = array_merge ( $circle_names, getCircleNames () );

$form ['circle_name'] = array (
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t ( 'Circle Name' ),
        '#options' => $circle_names,
        '#ajax' => array (
                'callback' => 'reports_populateOfficeName',
                'wrapper' => 'textbox-div',
                'method' => 'replace',
                'effect' => 'fade' 
        ),
        '#states' => array (
                'invisible' => array ( // Making circle name list invisible if report selected is PROBLEMS_REPORTED
                        ':input[name=choose_report]' => array (
                                array (
                                        'value' => PROBLEMS_REPORTED 
                                ),
                                array (
                                        'value' => ROLLOUT_PLANNING_REPORT 
                                ),
                                array (
                                        'value' => DE_STATUS_DASHBOARD 
                                )                                   
                        ) 
                ) 
        ) 
);

// Populating PO names dynamically
$circle_name = reset ( $circle_names );

if (! empty ( $form_state ['values'] ['circle_name'] )) {
    $circle_name = $form_state ['values'] ['circle_name'];
}

$office_names [ALL] = ALL;

$office_names = array_merge ( $office_names, getPONamesReports ( $circle_name ) );

$form ['office_name'] = array (
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t ( 'Office Name' ),
        '#options' => $office_names,
        '#prefix' => '<div id="textbox-div">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#states' => array (
                'invisible' => array ( // Making circle name list invisible if report selected is PROBLEMS_REPORTED
                        ':input[name=choose_report]' => array (
                                array (
                                        'value' => PROBLEMS_REPORTED 
                                ),
                                array (
                                        'value' => ROLLOUT_PLANNING_REPORT 
                                ),
                                array (
                                        'value' => DE_STATUS_DASHBOARD 
                                ) 
                        ) 
                ) 
        ) 
);

$form ['system_type'] = array (
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t ( 'System Type' ),
        '#options' => $system_types,
        '#states' => array (
                'visible' => array ( // Making circle name list visible if report selected is TRAINING_STATUS_REPORT
                        ':input[name=choose_report]' => array (
                                array (
                                        'value' => TRAINING_STATUS_REPORT 
                                ),
                        /*      array (
                                        'value' => CPC_STATUS_REPORT 
                                ),
                                array (
                                        'value' => BRANCH_HARDWARE_DETAILED_REPORT 
                                ),
                                array (
                                        'value' => BRANCH_HARDWARE_SUMMARY_REPORT 
                                ) 
                        */
                        ) 
                ) 
        ) 
);



$form ['migration_type'] = array (
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t ( 'Migration Type' ),
        '#options' => $migration_types,
        '#states' => array (
                'visible' => array ( // Making circle name list invisible if report selected is PROBLEMS_REPORTED
                        ':input[name=choose_report]' => array (
                                array (
                                        'value' => DATA_MIGRATION_SUMMARY_REPORT 
                                ),
                                array (
                                        'value' => DATA_MIGRATION_DETAILED_REPORT 
                                ) 
                        ) 
                ) 
        ) 
);

$form ['plan_type'] = array (
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t ( 'Plan Type' ),
        '#options' => $plan_types,
        '#states' => array (
                'visible' => array ( // Making circle name list invisible if report selected is PROBLEMS_REPORTED
                        ':input[name=choose_report]' => array (
                                array (
                                        'value' => ROLLOUT_PLANNING_REPORT 
                                ) 
                        ) 
                ) 
        ) 
);

$stored_date = get_stored_date_value ( $form_state, 'from_date' );

$form ['from_date'] = array (
        '#type' => 'date',
        '#title' => t ( 'From Date' ),
        '#value' => $stored_date,
        '#process' => array (
                'form_process_date',
                'fix_year_range_current' 
        ),
        '#states' => array (
                'visible' => array (
                        ':input[name=choose_report]' => array (
                                array (
                                        'value' => ROLLOUT_PLANNING_REPORT 
                                ) ,
                                array (
                                        'value' => DE_STATUS_DASHBOARD 
                                ) 
                        ) 
                ) 
        ) 
);

$stored_date = get_stored_date_value ( $form_state, 'to_date' );

$form ['to_date'] = array (
        '#type' => 'date',
        '#title' => t ( 'To Date' ),
        '#value' => $stored_date,
        '#process' => array (
                'form_process_date',
                'fix_year_range_current' 
        ),
        '#states' => array (
                'visible' => array (
                        ':input[name=choose_report]' => array (
                                array (
                                        'value' => ROLLOUT_PLANNING_REPORT 
                                ) ,
                                array (
                                        'value' => DE_STATUS_DASHBOARD 
                                ) 
                        ) 
                ) 
        ) 
);


$Vendor_Name [ALL] = ALL;
$Vendor_Name = array_merge ( $Vendor_Name, getVendorNames_O());

$form ['Vendor_Name'] = array (
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t ( 'Vendor Name' ),
        '#options' => $Vendor_Name,
        '#prefix' => '<div id="textbox-div">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#states' => array (
                'visible' => array ( // Making circle name list visible if report selected is POVsVendor_STATUS_SUMMARY_REPORT
                        ':input[name=choose_report]' => array (
                                array (
                                        'value' => POVsVendor_STATUS_SUMMARY_REPORT 
                                )
                        ) 
                ) 
        ) 
);



$form ['submit'] = array (
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t ( 'Generate Report' ),
        '#suffix' => '&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;' 
);

if (! empty ( $form_state ['results_table'] )) {
    if (! empty ( $form_state ['report_name'] )) {
        // code to generate link for downloading report
        $base_url = $GLOBALS ['base_url'];
        //$currentDate = date ( 'd-M-Y', time () );
        $currentDate = date ( "d-M-Y H:i:s");
        $form ['download'] = array (
                '#markup' => '<strong><a href="' . $base_url . REPORTS_URL . $form_state ['report_name'] . '">Download Report</a></strong> : As on '.$currentDate 
        );
    }

//   Code to display report in table format
$form ['table'] = $form_state ['results_table'];
}



return $form;
}
```